# How to initialize log system once in a multi-dll program?

Tags: logging, boost-log

I am using Boost Log to build my log system. In my program, there are many DLL components which is a common way to build the program.

I have a confusion. In each dll, I need to initialize the log system of its own and write to it's specific log file, or else the DLL can't output log messages. So in my program, I have to initialize the log many times. I initialize the log in the [Dll entry point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
switch( fdwReason ) 
{ 
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
     // Initialize once for each new process.
     // Return FALSE to fail DLL load.
        break;
```

By this way, if there are five dlls, I need to initialize the log five times with different log file which is a huge workload.

Is it possible to initialize the log once in the whole dlls? I want to share the log system in every dll.

Or is there any other kind of Log system support this?